# Div em círculos com layout responsivo

Tags: html, css, layout-responsivo

Estou tentando fazer uma página onde contenham umas `div` em círculos e que se ajustem uma abaixo da outra quando o *layout* diminuir, por exemplo, para tamanhos de celular.
Com o tamanho comum gostaria que ficassem 4 lado-a-lado e ao ir diminuindo fiquem uma abaixo da outra.
Li algo sobre *media queries* e estou tentando implementar, mas caso alguém conheça e pudesse me ajudar com algo.

Também não consigo deixar um pouco de espaço entre as `div`.

Segue o código que estou usando no momento:

```css
.center-content {
  border: solid 1px #000;
  width: 100%;
}

.center-content div {
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #229922;
}
```

```html
<div class="center-content">
  <div>Texto</div>
  <div>Texto</div>
  <div>Texto</div>
  <div>Texto</div>
  <br/>
  <div>Texto</div>
  <div>Texto</div>
  <div>Texto</div>
  <div>Texto</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Consegui achar duas alternativas:

1. Usando `inline-block`
2. Usando `inline-flex`

## Usando `inline-block`

Para ter mais abrangência pode usar o display `inline-block` assim:

```css
.master {
 border: solid 1px #000;
 max-width: 500px;
    font-size: 0;
}

.master div {
    border-radius: 50%;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 10px;
    width: 100px;
    line-height: 100px;
    background-color: #229922;
    font-size: 40px;
}

body{
    color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button onclick="$('.master').width($('.master').width()-25)">Clique para reduzir largura em 25px</button>
<button onclick="$('.master').width($('.master').width()+25)">Clique para reduzir largura em 25px</button>
<div class="master">
    <div>1</div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div>3</div>
    <div>4</div>
    <div>5</div>
    <div>6</div>
    <div>7</div>
    <div>8</div>
</div>
```

[jsFiddle: lá é mais fácil redimensionar com o mouse](http://jsfiddle.net/masbicudo/54fywqfm/)

## Usando `inline-flex`

Se você não tiver restrições em usar alguns CSS mais modernos como `inline-flex`, pode fazer assim:

```css
.master {
 border: solid 1px #000;
 max-width: 500px;
    font-size: 0;
}

.master div {
    border-radius: 50%;
    display: inline-flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    margin: 10px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: #229922;
    font-size: 40px;
}


body{
    color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button onclick="$('.master').width($('.master').width()-25)">Clique para reduzir largura em 25px</button>
<button onclick="$('.master').width($('.master').width()+25)">Clique para reduzir largura em 25px</button>
<div class="master">
    <div>1</div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div>3</div>
    <div>4</div>
    <div>5</div>
    <div>6</div>
    <div>7</div>
    <div>8</div>
</div>
```

[jsFiddle: lá é mais fácil redimensionar com o mouse](http://jsfiddle.net/masbicudo/dgrnjr4u/)

Comment: Não conhecia esse inline-flex... Funciona muito bem em IE10+, entretanto nada desse módulo Flexible Box Layout funciona no IE9... tem algum paralelo disso?

Comment: Até tem, mas ai tenho quase certeza que terá de mexer na estrutura do HTML.

Comment: Bem, de qualquer maneira funcionou muito bem para o restante... vale a melhor resposta. Vlw

Comment: @Marco Atualizei a resposta com uma outra alternativa, que usa `inline-block`. Eu estava errado, não será necessário alterar a estrutura para usar algo mais conhecido do CSS.

Comment: Tenho minhas dúvidas quanto esse `display:inline-flex` aplicado aos elementos filhos. Nessas técnicas de *flexbox*, geralmente quem recebe a regra é o elemento pai. Por exemplo, `.master { display: inline-flex; flex-flow: row wrap }` - [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sujoxtLq/1/).