# Centralizando #Menu #Nav na página com formas circulares?

Tags: html5, css3, bootstrap-3, grid, slim-lang

[image: Imagem do menu nav da landing page]

Esse é o Html dessa seção:

```
home
  #home.scroll
  br
  br
  .container
    .row
      a.scroll href="#oquee"
        .cir O que é
      a.scroll href="#local"
        .cir Local
      a.scroll href="#convidado"
        .cir Convidado
      a.scroll href="#contato"
        .cir Contato
      a.scroll href="#inscricao"
        .cir Inscrição
```

Bom dia, Gostaria de saber como eu poderia deixar esses círculos um do lado do outro, e centralizado na página ? Estou com uma landingpage para entregar na data de hoje.

eu já tentei ao aplicar `display: inline;` mais ele dá o seguinte erro

[image: erro display: inline;]

esse é o css que eu inseri:

```
.cir {
    background-color:#135d62;
    color:#fff;
    width:120px;
    height:120px;
    line-height:120px;
    vertical-align:middle;
    text-align:center;
    font-size: 18px;
    border-radius:50%;
    -moz-border-radius:50%;
    -webkit-border-radius:50%;
    display: inline;
}
```

como posso colocar cada circulo um do lado do outro e depois centralizar ? Pois já tentei com o sistema de Grid do Bootstrap mais ele não fica centralizado.

fica assim com o bootstrap:

[image: Grid Bootstrap]

html bootstrap

```
home
  #home.scroll
  br
  br
  .container
    .row
      .col-md-2
        a.scroll href="#oquee"
          .cir O que é
      .col-md-2
        a.scroll href="#local"
          .cir Local
      .col-md-2
        a.scroll href="#convidado"
          .cir Convidado
      .col-md-2
        a.scroll href="#contato"
          .cir Contato
      .col-md-2
        a.scroll href="#inscricao"
          .cir Inscrição
```

Desde já agradeço pela atenção.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tente usar `float:left` nos círculos para coloca-los lado a lado. Centralize usando um container e definindo `margin: auto;` e `align: center;` Lembrando que a largura do container tem que ser o espaço que os círculos ocupam, definido de forma fixa;

Por exemplo:

```
.cir {
    background-color:#135d62;
    color:#fff;
    width:120px;
    height:120px;
    line-height:120px;
    vertical-align:middle;
    text-align:center;
    font-size: 18px;
    border-radius:50%;
    -moz-border-radius:50%;
    -webkit-border-radius:50%;
    margin-right: 20px;
}

.espacador{ /*como você não quer os circulos colados...*/
 margin: 0px;
 width: 140px;
 height: 120px;
 float: left;
}



#container{
 width: 420px;
 height: 120px;
 margin: auto;
 align: center;
}

<div id="container">
 <div class="espacador">
  <div class="cir"></div>
 </div>
 <div class="espacador">
  <div class="cir"></div>
 </div>
 <div class="espacador">
  <div class="cir"></div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Em uma outra questão, já dei uma [resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/56108/1925) para resolver um problema parecido.

Adaptei o código para centralizar os círculos.

```css
.master {
  border: solid 1px #000;
  font-size: 0;
  text-align: center;
}
.master div {
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 10px;
  width: 100px;
  line-height: 100px;
  background-color: #229922;
  font-size: 40px;
}
body {
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button onclick="$('.master').width($('.master').width()-25)">Clique para reduzir largura em 25px</button>
<button onclick="$('.master').width($('.master').width()+25)">Clique para aumentar largura em 25px</button>
<div class="master">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
</div>
```